# responsive web design styling *updated*

Tags: css, text, responsive-design, styling, text-alignment

I'm still new at trying to make my website work in Responsive Web Design. Is there a way for me to make the `class="label"` align after I tried viewing it on different devices? I tried this:

[image]

This works perfectly. However, when I tried to view on different devices which provides portrait screen, it turned out to be like this:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/V4u5X/880/

> update!!!!

```
<div class="columnshop">
                        <div class="grid_1_of_4 images_1_of_4">
                            <div class="grid_preview">
                                <a href=""><img src="" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="price-details">
                                <span><a href="">Cabbage ( hidden,enabled)asndbbsddbsbsba</a></span>
                                <div class="price-number">$5.00</div>
                                <button id="addToCart" class="buttonlink">ADD TO CART</button>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/V4u5X/920/

How to get the text fixed within the *div*? For example, if the text is longer that the width of the ***class="grid_1_of_4 images_1_of_4"*** Even if the text is long, it should word break nicely within the div.

Comment: You need to use a grid system and design your layouts keeping various screen sizes in mind. Would highly recommend you to look into bootstrap : http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: you need to set width of the container and use float property for children

Comment: This actually happening for responsive text.

Comment: yeah it doesn't work for mine

Comment: @SitiNurainiYakob Try bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/ it's not that bad really. I started using it about 6 months ago and am pretty happy with it.

Comment: could you help me with the post i just update it? @aSeptik

Answer (score 1):

This is the responsive layout. You can change the media queries about that area. You just simply write that **class** `display:table-row`

Comment: hi! i have update my question. could you guide me on how i should solve it? @EastEnd

Answer (score 0):

If you want a  responsive web site,you should try to use CSS3 media queries

[CSS3 media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp)

and a good Tutorial of Responsive Web Design

[Responsive Web Design](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/your-first-multi-screen-site/?hl=en)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/V4u5X/880/ I unsure on how to add the media queries. But based on my example, how it should be done?

Comment: @SitiNurainiYakob what about this [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nutto/V4u5X/881/),but it is not a Responsive Web Design in strict sense.